# Reversing words in a string doesn't work

Tags: c++

I have assignment in c++, and I can't get it to work. I need to write a function that accepts two parameters, first is a string which should be sentence inputted by user, second should be a vector of strings also inputted by user. Function then needs to check first string (sentence) for any words from vector, and if there is same word, letters in word needs to switch, if not, nothing happens.
Example:
if my sentence is "Dwight is digging today."
and my vector string is "Dwight","Saturday", "Something", "digging"
words in string should then be "thgiwD", "Saturday","Something","gniggid".
For some reason, my function only applies this to first word in sentence, and I can't figure out why. Any help would be appreciated.

code of function is here:

```
string obrnifraze(string recenica, vector<string> pomocni_vektor) {
    string temp;
    for (vector<string>::size_type i = 0; i < pomocni_vektor.size(); i++) {
        temp = pomocni_vektor[i];
        if (recenica.find(temp) != string::npos) {
            reverse(temp.begin(), temp.end());
                cout << temp<<endl;
        }
    }
    return recenica;
}
```

Comment: [I get two lines of output](http://rextester.com/MCVJE92698), not one. Is this not what you expected? You only print `temp` if it was in fact found in `recenica`, so you only print those words you reverse, but not those you leave unchanged.

Comment: Yeah, but for me, I input two words in sentence "Pokusaj jedan"
and try both those words in a vector, and function prints only "Pokusaj" reversed.... I also tried with multiple words, I only get first word in a sentence reversed....

Comment: [Works for me](http://rextester.com/HUOR73347), too. Or perhaps I misunderstood your verbal description. Show an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Problem is because words need to be inserted by user, and I think I found where the error is because of your input. Problem is in my main function, in input of words. Now I think I can solve it. Thank you both for help.